# rails console populates with strange characters in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm getting some strange characters when I start rails console. The characters also appear on subsequent new lines if I delete the prior ones. This error doesn't happen in my terminal outside of visual studio code. I updated visual studio code today. I'm running rails in WSL2.

[rails console bug on start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SwLj.png)

Comment: I think this problem has nothing to do with Rails, it might be because of the terminal emulator you're using, multiplexer, IDE, editor, or any other. I recommend you to go step by step checking what might be the root of the problem, if any.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't seem to be a rails problem. As I mentioned it only comes up on terminals inside of visual studio code.

Comment: Same issue here. Just started a today. I am guessing something in a recent VS Code update cause this issue.

Comment: Did anybody find a solution so far?

Comment: I think it was fixed in the most recent VS Code update.

Comment: I am also having this issue nowadays in rails console. And there are no new updates in VSC. I am having it with normal "i" character being converted into "^[i". Anybody having a similar issue?